# Error: DTAssetProviderService could not start DTXConnection with Simulator 'iPhone 6'. Check the system log for errors

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, ios-simulator

**Hey there!**
I installed **macOS Sierra** and **XCode 8**. I played a bit with swift 3, but after some time I wanted to **get back to Swift 2**. So I started XCode 7, but when I tried to run an app on the simulator, **XCode showed an error**.

I've checked some other post about that problem and tried everything, but nothing works. ***I've already killed XCode and the Simulator, restarted my Mac, deleted the DerivedData, deleted XCode-beta and reinstalled XCode.***

Error: `DTAssetProviderService could not start DTXConnection with Simulator 'iPhone 6'. Check the system log for errors.`

System: Macbook Pro 13", 8GB Ram, 512GB SSD, Intel Core i5 2.8GHZ;

Don't know how to post the system.log, doesn't work with the code brackets. How can I upload the file?

EDIT: try this: http://www.mediafire.com/download/821qz82vwiky38t/system.log

I hope you can help me, sorry for my bad english, I'm Austrian :P

Answer (score 3):

I had Same problem. Use your device with development certificates. It will work on device with no errors. This issue is only with simulators.

For Simulator: Here is a workaround.

You Application has been installed to simulator. Run it from simulator now. To debug application use debug menu of Xcode to attach with application.

I assume this will be solved with release of stable version of macOS.

Thank you